# Can I install two Cuda toolkits and use them at the same time?

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, nvidia, cuda

I wonder if I can easily install multiple Cuda toolkits and use them.
The reason for this is that, I have two applications, that need two different versions.
Now if I create two user accounts, and install each version in each accounts, Will it be OK?
I mean will they not affect the whole system and thus other accounts?
Can I do this in one account?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.
As long as the Os is supported you can install several CUDA toolkits. In order not to face any issues, I, however, recommend using `runfile` installers as they allow you to specify which and where to install them.
One thing to look after is the symlink created for CUDA. when you install CUDA, usually many apps and/or frameworks check for that symlink which most often points to the latest/only version of CUDA available on a system.
So have the necessary changes in your application specific config file to point to the correct cuda installation version. The installer normally always creates a folder named `cuda-x.x` (e.g cuda-9.1) which you can use instead of the symlink (`/usr/local/cuda`) as well.
If one application of yours only checks the symlink `/usr/local/cuda`, and there is no way for you to alter its config, then you can make that symlinc point to the version of cuda, that app needs and the configure the other apps to use their corrosponding versions through their config files.